# angular directive executing before data fetch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an issue at the moment with a directive whereas some scope values that are set in the parent controller are not set when the directive tried to access them. This is because the directive is called before the AJAX call has returned any data. Is there any to make my directive wait for this data to be set before continuing?

```
angular.module('vt.directives', [])
    .directive('personType', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="{{data.property}}"</div>',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.personType);

        }
    };
}]);

<div ng-controller="parentcontroller">
  <div personType data="jsonobject"></div>
</div>
```

here my parentcontroller is fetching the data from service and passing to persontype directive, but persontype directive is not waiting untill jsonobject is fetching from service so it's causing many issues.

Comment: What is the harm if it does not wait ?

Comment: I think data is available in ``scope.data`` not in ``scope.personType`` in you directive link function.

Comment: When you do `scope: { data: '=' }` in the directive, you are setting up 2 way binding, so as the first comment says, there is no harm if it doesn't wait, b/c the binding should get updated again when the data is retrieved. Your console.log statement will only runs the once (it wouldn't print the server response, even if you used the right variable name). Are you showing us all of the template where the directive is used? If there is more, you could be creating child scopes which can cause this sort of problem.

Comment: Also, you should use `person-type` to call your directive from within your HTML.

Comment: Make use of $watch in your directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data at scope,personType then you have to assign data to personType directive itself

```
<div personType="jsonobject"></div>
```

and access it by

```
console.log( $parse(attrs.personType)(scope));
```

And if you want to load this data after AJAX call then you can $emit your data from your service and access it in your directive by $on method.

May be it helps in your case :)